# Generat .so file for a library for arm64

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just need help in generating .so file for a library. I am using this library for my project: https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo

I already asked the developers to generate libScanner.so for arm64 based devices but seems the developers are not already active. The app I made is perfectly working on the emulator but when I ran it on my Samsung Galaxy S8, it crashed because of the missing libScanner.so in arm64 folder of jniLibs.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: hey, how did you solved it? @JaysonTamayo